# SharePoint 2013 CA Review job definitions page displays file not found

Tags: central-administration, timer-jobs, monitoring

When I click on SharePoint 2013 CA -->Monitoring--> Review job definitions page, it displays file not found and all the timer jobs are paused.How to fix this?

Comment: Have you checked if the SharePoint Timer Service is running on the server?

Comment: @Sudhakar yes SharePoint Timer Service is running on the server

Answer (score 0):

you have to make sure Couple of things are working.

- Permission for Farm Admin account in place
- SharePoint Timer Service is running, try to Restart it.
- Clear the Config Cache if the issue is still there.
- also try to reboot the server.
- Any updates apply to the server?